# Length of a curve given by an equation $ r(t)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the length of the space curve given by $$r(t) = 2t\,\mathbf{i} + 5\cos(t)\,\mathbf{j} + 5\sin(t)\,\mathbf{k}$$ over the interval $[0,2]$.

I did this and I got the answer as 10.77

Did I get the right answer? please help me i'm not very good at this.

Comment: What method did you use? Here $\vec{r}=(2t,5\cos{t},5\sin{t})$, and calculating $\int_0^2|r'(t)|\mathrm{d}t$ gives you the arc length of the curve (what you are after), and this turns out to be roughly $10.77$, as you got.

Comment: Your answer is inccorect. The correct answer is $2\sqrt{29}$. Although $2\sqrt{29} \approx 10.77$, $2\sqrt{29} \neq 10.77$. The answer $10.77$ is correct to two decimal places. It is wrong for infinitely many more decimal places,

Comment: It seems your work is fine, and that the only point of contention here is about the need to be careful about giving answers that are mere approximations. **Unless otherwise told** , $2 \sqrt{29}$ cannot be further simplified and is the *exact solution*. Unless otherwise told, use the *exact* form of the solution and not its approximation $\approx 10.77$

Comment: Dear bob: I would encourage you to take a few moments to review answers you have received, and accept **one** answer per question you've asked. (An "asker" can only accept one answer to any given question asked.) To accept an answer, just click on the $\large \checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept.  May I also note that you can now, also, upvote as many answers as you'd like!

Answer (score 4):

Yes and no. The correct answer is $2\sqrt{29} \approx 10.77$.

$$\int_a^b \sqrt{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2+\dot{z}^2} \, \operatorname{d}\! t $$

In your example, $x(t) = 2t$, $y(t) = 5 \cos t$ and $z(t) = 5 \sin t$. Hence $\dot{x}(t) = 2$, $\dot{y}(t) = -5\sin t $ and $\dot{z}(t) = 5\cos t$. In turn 
\begin{array}{ccc}
\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2+\dot{z}^2 &=& 2^2 + (-5\sin t)^2 + (5 \cos t)^2 \\
&\equiv& 4 + 25\sin^2 t + 25\cos^2t \\
&\equiv& 4 + 25(\sin^2t + \cos^2 t) \\
&\equiv& 4 + 25 \\
&=& 29
\end{array}
The length of the curve is then:
$$\int_0^2 \sqrt{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2+\dot{z}^2} \, \operatorname{d}\!t = \int_0^2 \sqrt{29} \, \operatorname{d}\!t = 2\sqrt{29}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:$$L=\int_0^{2}|r'(t)|dt$$ then $\int_0^{2}|r'(t)|dt=\int_0^{2}\sqrt{25+4}dt=2\sqrt{29}\sim 10.7703$

Comment: is my answer wrong then?

Comment: @bob adam:your answer is exactly  true